# ggplot: Add annotation for each bin in a (double) grouped boxplot; Figuring out the x-position

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, boxplot

I am sorry for the long dput, but this is the data I am using:

```
structure(list(precip_class = c("p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", 
"p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", 
"p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", 
"p15", "p15", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", 
"p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", 
"p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3"), p_precip = c(16.0999998599291, 
20.3000000119209, 59.9999995827675, 124.900001205504, 76.4999992847443, 
123.49999922514, 76.8999986797571, 24.2999995350838, 50.9000000953674, 
105.400000572205, 153.600005090237, 175.999998450279, 146.699999392033, 
128.199999034405, 54.2000019103289, 44.2000003233552, 27.1000000238419, 
18.4000003710389, 127.600000098348, 68.8999996185303, 47.5999994277954, 
75.5999999642372, 92.7000005245209, 94.3000001907349, 25.5000002384186, 
0, 10.7999999523163, 46.7000004053116, 17, 0, 0, 189.500003814697, 
73.9000015258789, 139.200000762939, 77.7999992370605, 18.8999996185303, 
0.100000001490116, 31.5000004768372, 2.10000002384186, 22, 16.9999996423721, 
0, 61.3000007867813, 29.4999992847443, 18.2000007629395, 12.5999999046326, 
48.3999992012978, 0.100000001490116, 0, 18.2999996244907), geo_class = c("Calcschists with ophiolites", 
"Calcschists with ophiolites", "Calcschists with ophiolites", 
"Calcschists with ophiolites", "Calcschists with ophiolites", 
"Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", 
"Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", "Plutonite", 
"Plutonite", "Plutonite", "Plutonite", "Plutonite", "Porphyry", 
"Porphyry", "Porphyry", "Porphyry", "Porphyry", "Sedimentary rocks", 
"Sedimentary rocks", "Sedimentary rocks", "Sedimentary rocks", 
"Sedimentary rocks", "Calcschists with ophiolites", "Calcschists with ophiolites", 
"Calcschists with ophiolites", "Calcschists with ophiolites", 
"Calcschists with ophiolites", "Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", 
"Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", "Crystalline basement", 
"Plutonite", "Plutonite", "Plutonite", "Plutonite", "Plutonite", 
"Porphyry", "Porphyry", "Porphyry", "Porphyry", "Porphyry", "Sedimentary rocks", 
"Sedimentary rocks", "Sedimentary rocks", "Sedimentary rocks", 
"Sedimentary rocks"), med = c(76.4999992847443, 76.4999992847443, 
76.4999992847443, 76.4999992847443, 76.4999992847443, 69.9500006735325, 
69.9500006735325, 69.9500006735325, 69.9500006735325, 69.9500006735325, 
76.8000005334616, 76.8000005334616, 76.8000005334616, 76.8000005334616, 
76.8000005334616, 66.3000008612871, 66.3000008612871, 66.3000008612871, 
66.3000008612871, 66.3000008612871, 75.4499996006489, 75.4499996006489, 
75.4499996006489, 75.4499996006489, 75.4499996006489, 13.2999995946884, 
13.2999995946884, 13.2999995946884, 13.2999995946884, 13.2999995946884, 
21.6000000014901, 21.6000000014901, 21.6000000014901, 21.6000000014901, 
21.6000000014901, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 18.2000007629395, 18.2000007629395, 
18.2000007629395, 18.2000007629395, 18.2000007629395, 25.8500002622604, 
25.8500002622604, 25.8500002622604, 25.8500002622604, 25.8500002622604
), n = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(
    precip_class = c("p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", 
    "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", 
    "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", "p15", 
    "p15", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", 
    "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", "p3", 
    "p3"), p_precip = c(16.0999998599291, 18.4000003710389, 20.3000000119209, 
    24.2999995350838, 25.5000002384186, 27.1000000238419, 44.2000003233552, 
    47.5999994277954, 50.9000000953674, 54.2000019103289, 59.9999995827675, 
    68.8999996185303, 75.5999999642372, 76.4999992847443, 76.8999986797571, 
    92.7000005245209, 94.3000001907349, 105.400000572205, 123.49999922514, 
    124.900001205504, 127.600000098348, 128.199999034405, 146.699999392033, 
    153.600005090237, 175.999998450279, 0, 0.100000001490116, 
    2.10000002384186, 10.7999999523163, 12.5999999046326, 16.9999996423721, 
    17, 18.2000007629395, 18.2999996244907, 18.8999996185303, 
    22, 29.4999992847443, 31.5000004768372, 46.7000004053116, 
    48.3999992012978, 61.3000007867813, 73.9000015258789, 77.7999992370605, 
    139.200000762939, 189.500003814697), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 18L, 2L, 8L, 25L, 17L, 16L, 21L, 9L, 15L, 3L, 20L, 
        22L, 5L, 7L, 23L, 24L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 19L, 14L, 13L, 11L, 
        12L, c(26L, 30L, 31L, 42L, 49L), c(37L, 48L), 39L, 27L, 
        46L, 41L, 29L, 45L, 50L, 36L, 40L, 44L, 38L, 28L, 47L, 
        43L, 33L, 35L, 34L, 32L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 45L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I would like to create a boxplot that is similar to this:

[image]

I split the boxplot by the variable `precip_class` and then I color it using the variable `geo_class`. This is the code that made the plot

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(
         x = precip_class,
         y = p_precip,
         color = geo_class,
         fill = med
       )) +
  geom_boxplot(size = .2) +
  scico::scale_fill_scico(palette = "bilbao") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(rep("black", 5)))
```

Now I would like to add for each group the number of datapoints. Getting them is easy by doing so:

```
df %>% group_by(precip_class, p_precip) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) -> df
```

However I have no idea how I could find for each bin the right x-position. I tried something like:

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(
         x = precip_class,
         y = p_precip,
         color = geo_class,
         fill = med
       )) +
  geom_boxplot(size = .2) +
  geom_label(
    aes(
      x = precip_class,
      y = med + 10, 
      label = med 
    )
  ) +
  scico::scale_fill_scico(palette = "bilbao") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(rep("black", 5)))
```

But they all line up in the same x position like so:
Maybe I could add some `ifelse`-s in the `x`-parameter in the `aes`-call for the label. But I feel like there might be a better option.

[image]

Comment: Try with `geom_label(..., position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))`. There is already an answer on this but I can't find it as of the moment. (:

Comment: Thank you very very much! I will try this approach and also look for this answer;)

Comment: I do not know how, but it worked!! Thank you so much. I definitly need to read more on this

Comment: (: The issue is the `position`. By default geom_boxplot uses `position_dodge` with a width of .75 which means that the position is adjusted to put the box plots side by side. In contrast `geom_label` (or _text or _point or ...) uses `position_identity` which means that the position is not adjusted. Hence we have to tell ggplot to use position_dodge for the labels as well.